# Oracle ATG: New payment group issue, amount of the payment group has invalid values

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

I have added a new `PaymentGroup` for our Ecommerce site for store-points redemption based on the documentation.

After submitting an order (store points + cash), I could see that the final amount of the store points `PaymentGroups` is incorrect.

It seems the amount is a cumulative sum of the points amount of previous orders.

When debugging I saw following in `PaymentGroupFormHandler.applyPaymentGroups()` method, `List commerceIdentifierPaymentInfos = container.getAllCommerceIdentifierPaymentInfos();`

This list contains the `PaymentInfo` of the previous order as well. So, the `pgm.recalculatePaymentGroupAmounts(order)` gives a cumulative summation of previous points redemptions.

Still I couldn't find the root cause for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the scope of your `PaymentGroupFormHandler`? If it is any thing other than `request` you may have this issue.

Comment: The "PaymentGroupFormHandler" has the scope "request".

Comment: Did you read thi [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGCommProgGuide/html/s1508extendingordervalidationtosuppor01.html) carefult. May be problem happens when you validate payment group by type. Try read alse [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGCommProgGuide/html/s3102validatepaymentgrouppipelinechai01.html) page